# How to configure anon UI for Plone add-on: EEA Faceted Navigation?

Tags: plone

I have a default [EEA faceted navigation](http://plone.org/products/eea.facetednavigation) setup (nice add-on, by the way). Works great, but I can't figure out how (TTW) to present the facet UI to anon.

Here is the logged in view:

[image]

And here is the anon view:

[image]

For the purposes of this question, I'd like anon to see current search and portal type "portlets", but I can't figure out how to configure this (again TTW, have not looked at code or ZMI or anything like that.)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The faceted navigation UI only shows up if there is more than one page of results. If you publish all those private items it should show up.

Comment: Yep, this is super not-obvious.  :-)

Comment: In fact, the default batch size is 20 (you told me this in IRC)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with **eea.facetednavigation 4.6** you can explicitly disable **smart facets hiding** from the **Faceted settings** menu.

Comment: Starting with **eea.facetednavigation 5.2** (finally) this is disabled by default for new faceted navigable pages

Answer (score 1):

From the mantainers of the package:

==================

Hi,

"This is not a bug, it's a feature" :)

Indeed it's a feature (but I think we should drop it, or make it more explicit as it always ends with this confusion).

The description of this feature is like:

"If there is only one page of results (no batch) with no criteria selected by user (first display of the page), facets/widgets should be hidden as it is useless to filter 5 documents."

- To test this feature, go to a faceted navigable page that seems to have this "bug" and displays at least 5 items;
- Now add a new hidden facet for "results per page" and set it to 2;
- Your facets should be visible now."

Comment: Sounds reasonable. In this case, I'd suggest adding a message to the UI "no facets avail" to avoid confusion.